# How to not lose elements with same values from a TreeMap?

Tags: java

```
class CompoundKey implements Comparable<CompoundKey>{
        String key;
        Integer count;

        public CompoundKey(String key, Integer count){
            this.key = key;
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(@Nonnull CompoundKey other) {
            return (other.count.compareTo(this.count));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<CompoundKey, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put(new CompoundKey("a", 3), 3);
        map.put(new CompoundKey("b", 1), 1);
        map.put(new CompoundKey("c", 8), 8);
        map.put(new CompoundKey("d", 3), 3);
        map.put(new CompoundKey("e", 9), 9);

        for (CompoundKey key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key.key + "->" + map.get(key));
        }
    }
```

This will print out as below:

```
e->9
c->8
a->3
b->1
```

In the print out, the 'd->3' is missing. The purpose of this implementation is to create a map sorted by value when element is inserted (I don't need an implementation that will sort the map after all are inserted).

Is there some minor modification of my code to not lose the element with duplicate values? In the case of two duplicate values, the sorting order can be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to factor in the String as part of your `Comparable`.  For instance (your exact logic *may* want to vary):

```
public int compareTo(CompoundKey other) {
    return other.count.compareTo(this.count) + other.key.compareTo(this.key);
}
```

Because it only looks at numbers right now, it will only ever count numerals as being *the* natural order.  You need to include `key` as a part of this.

Comment: What about if the Integer is less, but "Integer + String" makes the result of comparison flipped? The impact of the 'key' is unpredictable to me.

Comment: Again - you'll want to investigate and see what works for you, but the factor of the comparable value of the string and the comparable value of the integer *should* be what you're looking for.  Since strings compare lexicographically, it could be that you wind up with a collision.  Take the above as advice and not as authoritative, but you absolutely *do* need to factor both values into your comparison.

Comment: Yes. I got your idea, and slightly changed my code, and it works. I updated and please take a look.

Comment: I've rolled your edit back @user697911 so as to not invalidate your original question.  I'm glad this gave you a nudge in the right direction, at least.